# Set precision and scale while saving into Db using entity framework

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, decimal

This is what the JSON response is:

```
{
  "data": [
    {
      "someTicketNum": "123456",
      "someTemperature": 2,
      "somePercent": 2.025
    }
  ]
}
```

The table it needs to be saved to is modeled as:

```
public class TableName
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public long TicketID { get; set; }
    public float? SomeTemperature { get; set; }
    public decimal? SomePercent { get; set; }
}
```

These Db columns are set up as: `SomeTemperature(decimal(3,1), null)` and `SomePercent(decimal(7,5), null)`.

I want values for these properties to be saved as follows:

```
SomeTicketNum: "123456",
SomeTemperature: 2.0,  // The examples values are: 0.0, 1.5, 99.9 etc.
SomePercent: 2.02500 // The example values are: 0.00000, 1.50000, 99.99999 etc.
```

I've tried this in the model builder:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<TableName>().Property(x => x.SomeTemperature).HasPrecision(3,1);
modelBuilder.Entity<TableName>().Property(x => x.SomePercent).HasPrecision(7, 5);
```

Turns out `.HasPrecision` can only be set in `decimal` properties so I changed data type of `SomeTemperature` to `decimal?` which made the error go away that was originally saying:

```
'PrimitivePropertyConfiguration' does not contain a definition for 'HasPrecision' and no accessible extension method 'HasPrecision' accepting a first argument of type 'PrimitivePropertyConfiguration' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
```

I just cannot figure out this `exception` while trying to save this record to `Db`, which says:

```
Inner Ex. Msg: String or binary data would be truncated. The statement has been terminated.
```

I've aligned all the data type in db and c# model.

What am I doing wrong here?
P.S. I'm using EF6.

Comment: You seem to be mixing things quite a lot here. JSON format -> irrelevant. C# format -> irrelevant. DB format -> relevant. Entity Framework will use the correct DB format based on the C# values that you have. And **no**, just because you see `SomeTemperature` as `2.00` it means that the value is `2.00`

Comment: Can you describe what actual problem is?

Comment: Hi @GuruStron, I added more details to the question now.

Comment: Try using `.HasColumnType("decimal(3,1)")` and `.HasColumnType("decimal(7,5)")`  correspondingly instead of `HasPrecision`.

Comment: @GuruStron I added `.HasColumnType("decimal(3,1)")`, and I'm getting this exception while fetching a row from that table: 
`The store type 'decimal(4,1)' could not be found in the SqlServer provider manifest.`

Comment: Change type of `SomeTemperature` to decimal and use `HasPrecision`.

Comment: @GuruStron Thank you so much, that did the trick!

Comment: @AshK will add as an answer than)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your approach with `HasPrecision` should work:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<TableName>().Property(x => x.SomeTemperature).HasPrecision(3,1);
modelBuilder.Entity<TableName>().Property(x => x.SomePercent).HasPrecision(7, 5);
```

The issues is that `HasPrecision` is defined only for [`decimal`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.entity.modelconfiguration.configuration.decimalpropertyconfiguration.hasprecision?view=entity-framework-6.2.0) (and `DateTime` but it is not relevant here) properties, so you need to change `SomeTemperature` property type to `decimal?`.

Answer (score 1):

About the exception:

```
Inner Ex. Msg: String or binary data would be truncated. The statement has been terminated.
```

I was attempting to save some other field with hard coded value like this:

```
SomeOtherField = (decimal)0.00000
```

Floating point numbers cannot be saved to a decimal field (`SomeOtherField` is a decimal), so changing it to:

```
SomeOtherField = 0.00000m
```

did the trick!